# Issue with sending nested json objects to sqlite db

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a large file of json objects that is one object per line.  I would like to send this data to a sqlite database.  Each json object is formatted like this:

```
{"1": {"google": 5},
 "2": "",
 "3": 0.0,
 "4": [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 20.0],
 "6": "",
 "7": 2,
 "8": {},
 "9": 1.0,
 "10": 0.0}
```

I tried this code and got the following error:

```
query = "insert into daily values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

columns = ['1', '2', '3', '4',
           '5', '6','7',
           '8', '9', '10']

with open(JSON_FILE) as f:
    head = islice(f, 5)
    for x in head:
        line = json.loads(x)
        keys = tuple(line[c] for c in columns)
        c.execute(query, keys)

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Two questions:

1) Why am I getting this error? I assume it has something to do with the the first hey's value being a nested dict, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

2)  Currently I created the table like this:

```
c.execute('''create table daily
         (1 text,
          2 text,
          3 text,
          4 text,
          5 text,
          6 text,
          7 text,
          8 text,
          9 text,
          10 text)''')
```

Ideally, I would like to have separate columns for the key:value pair for the first key in the object.  Again, I assume this is possible, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: As long as you've got JSON, why not NoSQL?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi  That's a good question.  Well, I've never worked with NoSQL before, so that's probably why.  But, trying to put this JSON into a sqlite db is giving me a real headache.  Would you recommend mongo or another nosql db??

Comment: Yes, definitely use Monogo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `MongoClient` connected to a running server, just `insert` the `json` into the database:

```
client.db.collection.insert(json) # insert the json in the collection of a database db
```

To retrieve the entries simply, use the `find` method of the given `collection` of the database `db`:

```
entries = client.db.collection.find() # find the entries without a specified argument
```

Comment: Document databases do away with the table-and-row model altogether, storing all relevant data together in single "document" in JSON, XML, or another format, which can nest values hierarchically.

Comment: This comment was taken from the [article](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained) NoSQL Explained.